# Edit HTML through Javascript function real time

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to show a "spinner loader" when a user clicks a button that fires a function which takes some time, so the user knows that stuff is being done in the back-end. I am writing in **VueJS** the front-end. The spinner is being shown only after the function has finished its job, which is something I do not want as my goal is that the spinner is shown as long as the function is run and the user wait.

```
// Unlock is a prompt page that contains a "Success" button and a "Cancel" button 

<unlock v-model="password" @cancel="cancel" @success="add"/>
<icon type="spinner" class="spin" v-if="loading"></icon>

methods: {
    async add() {
        this.loading = true
        this.error = ''
        await this.$store.dispatch('DO_SOMETHING', { users: this.selected_users, password: this.password })
        this.loading = false
        this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_PROMPT', '')
    }
...
...
}
```

I expected the spinner to show up as soon as the function is fired up, until it finishes when another page loads either way. I would like the spinner to be shown as long as we wait for the `await this.$store.dispatch('DO_SOMETHING')` to execute completely. Problem is, it is shown only after the whole function gets finished.

I tried playing around with the `async` and `await`, no results. Is it possible to show the element in HTML-VueJS directly, or this is something that just we cannot do it through Javascript?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The `action`

```
DO_SOMETHING: ({ commit, dispatch, state }, { users, password }) => {
    commit('SET_LOADING', true)
    const results = JSON.stringify(users.map( x => {
        if (...) delete ...
        if (...) delete ...
        return x
    }))
    API.addUser(results, password || state.password)
    // refresh page
    return dispatch('FETCH_PAGE')
},
```

The API.addUser, makes a call to the backend, where a Java function is run that makes the modifications in the database.

**EDIT v2:**
I added the following `console.log()`

```
    console.log("1")
    await this.$store.dispatch('DO_SOMETHING', { users: this.selected_users, password: this.password })
    console.log("6")




    console.log("2")
    API.addUsers(results, password || state.password)
    console.log("5")
```

The below is in the `API/addUsers()` function.

```
    console.log("3")
    const results = JSON.parse(window.UserbaseApplication.addUsers(users, password))
    console.log("4")
```

As expected, the results are:
1
2
3
4
5
6

So the function is awaiting the return of the API as expected.

Comment: is `this.$store.dispatch('DO_SOMETHING')` really an `async` function ?

Comment: I also expect that your `action` is not declared as an `async` function. Could you show us the `action`? Also, what do you mean by the spinner is shown only after the whole function gets finished; it should be hidden after the function finishes due to the `this.loading = false`

Comment: you should use `await` in front of `API.addUser` if it's async

Comment: @MarcRo Please see above. Also what I mean is that as soon as the new page loads, which happens with:

```this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_PROMPT', '')
```
The spinner is shown for like 0.1 seconds and then disappears.

Comment: @Ja9ad335h Tried. Didn't work. Same result, spinner is shown after the function finishes execution. Maybe I do something wrong in 
```vue-js``` or there is a workaround in that?

Comment: @PavTze Your `action` is not valid. You expect a second parameter, but you dont pass one when you dispatch the action (`this.$store.dispatch('DO_SOMETHING')`). `users` and `password` are both undefined.

Comment: @MarcRo Sorry, forgot to add it. Edited. The code and the function works like a charm, there is no problem in that.

Comment: Allright! Then there is still the catch that @Ja9ad335h mentioned - you need to await your API call (that's the whole reason you make this function async). If that is not working please show us your `API / API.addUser()`

Comment: @MarcRo The function waits as expected the API call. It doesn't proceed unless the API call returns. The problem I encounter is that I want the spinner/loader to run all this time the function waits the API, but it doesn't.

Comment: My apologies if we have a missunderstanding here. But from the code you posted it seems that your async function does not await the API call. This is the reason your spinner shows up for a split second. You could add a `console.log()` after your `API.addUser()` and also **inside** your `addUser()` function to validate your or our point! :) - If we are mistaken, I would be very curious to investigate why!

Comment: @MarcRo Please see the latest edit. I added the console logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200095/discussion-between-pavtze-and-marcro).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Vue, but in vanilla JS:

Lets say you have a user press a button, which calls a function that runs some computation. During the computation, you have a loader ready to go.

```
const button = document.querySelector(".mybutton")
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const loader = document.querySelector(".myloader");
  loader.style.display = "inline-block";
  // we are assuming the loader covers the whole width & height, with a black filter in the background
  // therefore, we don't have to hide other elements
  myfunction(...).then(
    res => {   
      // hide the loader after successful promise call
      loader.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

This example assumes that your function returns a promise

Same can be achieved with async/await

```
const myfunction = async function() {
  const res = await .... some computation
  return res
}

const button = document.querySelector(".mybutton")
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const loader = document.querySelector(".myloader");
      loader.style.display = "inline-block";
      // we are assuming the loader covers the whole width & height, with a black filter in the background
      // therefore, we don't have to hide other elements
      const result = myfunction();
      loader.style.display="none";
    });
```